# Hive 3.1.3 : "schemaTool -initSchema -dbType derby" throws java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hive.beeline.HiveSchemaTool

Tags: hadoop, hive

**Problem**
I'm trying to install Hive based on https://sparkbyexamples.com/apache-hive/apache-hive-installation-on-hadoop/ .

Running the following command: `schematool -initSchema -dbType derby` produces the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hive.beeline.HiveSchemaTool
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:387)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:321)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:241)
```

**My attempts to resolve**

1. Checked CLASSPATH

```
echo $CLASSPATH
/home/ameledin/hadoop/apache-hive-3.1.3-bin/lib/*:/home/ameledin/hadoop/hadoop-3.3.5/lib/*:/home/ameledin/hadoop/hadoop-handbook:
```

2. Checked lib/hive-beeline-3.1.3.jar contains //org/apache/hive/beeline/HiveSchemaTool.class

**Question**: What else to try?

Comment: Tried "java -cp /home/ameledin/hadoop/apache-hive-3.1.3-bin/lib/hive-beeline-3.1.3.jar org.apache.hive.beeline.HiveSchemaTool" directly. But got:
Error: Unable to initialize main class org.apache.hive.beeline.HiveSchemaTool
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/hive/metastore/HiveMetaException

Comment: Rather than set classpath at the OS level, I'd recommend setting in hive-env.sh file in the conf folder

Comment: @OneCricketeer: Can you point to documentation of how to this? It seems there is a bug for 4.0.0 https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-19774 . However, it should not relate to 3.1.3 version.

Comment: I'm not aware of any. Hive comes with that file, rather than following the blog that says to modify your bashrc. There should also be a `hive classpath` command, rather than echo-ing a shell variable

Comment: @OneCricketeer  ./bin/hive classpath command produces: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jline/console/completer/ArgumentCompleter$ArgumentDelimiter

Comment: Best guess is that your downloaded Hive package is corrupt, and missing many needed libraries. Those classes should be there. I've had previous problems with Antivirus Firewall removing packages, for example. Also, ensure you are using Java 11

Comment: @OneCricketeer: Seems something like this. Finally, installed normally on another Win10 computer running WSL2...

Answer (score 0):

As @OneCricketeer suggested in his comment, it seems I downloaded corrupt package. Installed on another win10 computer running WSL2 without any problem.